# spark section builder creation

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

the code has been working properly before and after some time the error has been threw by the google colab notebook while creating the section

the python code is:

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("local[*]").getOrCreate()
spark
```

this is the error i am getting

```
1 import pyspark
      2 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
----> 3 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("local[*]").getOrCreate()
      4 spark

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
--> 330                 raise Py4JError(
    331                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332                     format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession([class org.apache.spark.SparkContext, class java.util.HashMap]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:179)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:196)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:237)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: What is the version of your `pyspark` and `spark` ?